# Use lldb to find a non-external symbol named like '_OBJC_IVAR_$_DIRect._width' in main binary?

Tags: lldb

I know how to use `image lookup -n` with a symbol name. But seems '_OBJC_IVAR_$_DIRect._width' contain a `.` in its name, lldb can't handle this as a normal case.

`_OBJC_IVAR_$_DIRect._width` is a symbol generated by compiler.

> (__DATA,__objc_ivar) non-external (was a private external) _OBJC_IVAR_$_DIRect._width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-n is supposed to look for "function-or-symbol" - i.e. things that have debug information as well as symbols that come from the symbol table.  It is supposed to be equivalent to supplying `-F` and `-s` with the same argument.  But it actually only looks for functions and CODE symbols - it doesn't look for data symbols.  Not sure whether that's by design and the help string is just wrong or it's a bug.

Fortunately, the straight symbol lookup (using the `-s` option instead of `-n`) does search all symbols, including data symbols.  Try using the `-s` option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the `-s` option, but still can't match anything. You can try any Cocoa App with `image lookup -s _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject`.

Comment: Ah, you've stumbled on a fairly subtle bit of esoterica.  The first _ of a symbol name as reported by "nm" is not part of the symbol name for anyone but the linker.  Do "nm" on libsystem_c.dylib and grep for "printf". You won't see a symbol called `printf`, you'll see a symbol called `_printf`.  That first `_` is what the linker uses to distinguish compiler generated symbols from ones it uses for its own purposes.  It would be really confusing if debuggers reported that first _ in the symbol names, so they always strip them off.  Try stripping the leading _ and you should have better luck.